# Pronunciation of musical notes

Tags: pronunciation

Taking the note G as an example, I know that in German G♭ is written 'Ges' and G♯ is written 'Gis'.  But how are these pronounced?  My dictionary gives me the spelling but not the pronunciation.

I would guess that you say two syllables: the name of the letter 'G' followed by 'es' or 'is' – is this correct?

Comment: Also note (pun not intended) that in German, it's a H instead of B and H♭ is called B in German.

Answer (score 6):

In both cases it is spelled and pronounced as one word. Both *'-es'* [flat] and *'-is'* [sharp] are added.

**Ges** [G Flat] is pronounced like 'guess' in English (but with the 'u' not stressed too much]. ***Gis*** [G Sharp] in German sounds like *'kiss'* with the 'k' spelled as soft as in *"guess"* …, like *'giss'*.

Most musicians I know use Gsharp and Gflat because C, D, E, and G sound quite familiar :). In case one isn't sure, s_he uses the Ges for G Flat and so on.

**EDIT**

I seem to have been informed wrongly on **Geses** e.a. and I am deeply sorry for havin spread that misinformation! I didn't delete my text below to keep up the context of the comments.

There is also a hardly outside classical music used variations like **Geses** [G Flat Flat = F] and **Gisis** [G Sharp Sharp = A]. This would be spelled like *'guesses'* and '*gisses'*. You might find this used among some classical musicians, but very rarely, as it makes no real sense.

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't really answer the question.  First of all when you say "spelled" I suppose you mean "pronounced" (Ges is not spelled like "guess").  Then "…the 'k' spelled as soft as in guess...like 'giss'" – that doesn't mean anything, I'm afraid.  There is no 'k' in 'guess', and if you mean the 'g', it's hard, not soft.  But thank you for trying.

Comment: OT: Geses is not F. "Ces-Es-Ges" is a C-flat major chord. "Ces-It-Gesses" is a reduced C-flat major chord. Since F does not belong to the key of C-flat major key, "Ces-It-F" is just a collection of sounds. Enharmonic equivalents are good. But there are instruments beyond the piano, that differentiate between pitches like Dis and Es. They are diffent strings and pedals on the harp. This differnetiation makes modern (non-classical) pieces like J.Williams STAR WARS Suite playable on the harp. So it makes sense, even if it might be not obvious.

Comment: Again I'm sorry, but I don't think anyone has read my question. I'm not asking what the notes are called – I know that.  I'm only asking how the German names are pronounced.

Comment: For instance, I know that the German names of English G sharp and G flat are, respectively, 'Gis' and 'Ges'.  But is Gis in German pronounced as 'Giß' (one syllable) or 'G-iß' (two syllables)?  Similarly, is Ges pronounced as 'Geß' or 'G-eß'?

Comment: @abacus In each case only one syllable. The second paragraph of the above Answer already states that.

Comment: That answer has been altered.  In its present form I agree that it answers my question – in the first sentence, in fact.

Comment: @abacus: "G-iß" und "G-eß" hat als Beispiel für Aussprache auch keinen Sinn, denn ein einzelnes "G" hat keinen eigenen Laut und klingt folglich auch nicht. Ein alleinstehendes G wird Geh genannt, und folglich müsste die Frage dann lauten, ob es Geheß und Gehiß gesprochen wird. ;)

Comment: @userunknown: I don't see the necessity in making it more difficult as it already might be for people who aren't native speakers. This is just confusing.

Comment: "G-iß" und "G-eß" hat als Beispiel für Aussprache auch keinen Sinn...?  Wieso?  G-dur und G-moll (oder g-dur und g-moll) werden so geschrieben und ohne Probleme ausgesprochen.

Comment: @abacus: Sie werden G-Dur geschrieben, aber Geh-Dur gesprochen, nicht G-Dur oder Gdur.

Comment: Being a native German speaker, I don't know why you don't accept user2693's answer. I found his explanation excellent, and I'll try to make it even more clear and to add minor corrections: He wrote "... the u not stressed too much". But there is absolutely no bit of a "u" in the German "Ges". So take the English word "guess" and remove all parts of the pronunciation which refer to the "u" completely. Regarding the German "Gis", the English "kiss" is a good starting point. Replace the "k" in "kiss" by a "g" *and pronounce that "g" like you pronounce the "g" in "guess"*, and you are fine.